# Typing Nondeterministically Deep Array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array, typescript-typings

I'm currently porting some **Javascript** code to **Typescript**. I have a function which is essentially equivalent to the following:

```js
let deepArray = [];
function deeper() {
  if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
    deepArray.push(deeper());
  } else {
    deepArray.push("No deeper.");
  }
  return deepArray;
}
deeper();
```

I was wondering if there's a simple way to assign a type to `deepArray` and the return type of `deeper`. Obviously, it's a `string[]` of some depth, but as mentioned, that depth is indeterminate. I'd like to keep the code as similar to the original as possible, so avoiding changing data structures is the goal. Is this possible, or should I mark it as `any` and move on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a type that represents an arbitrarily nested array:

```
interface NestedArray<T> extends Array<T | NestedArray<T>> {
}
let deepArray: NestedArray<string> = [];

function deeper() {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
        deepArray.push(deeper());
    } else {
        deepArray.push("No deeper.");
    }
    return deepArray;
}
deeper();
console.log(deepArray)
```